# finding minimum values from a cut table Lua 5.1.5

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a Lua script that turns a table into segments:

```
function tablecut(t, n)
    local result = {}
    local j = 0
    for i = 1, #t do
        if (i-1) % n == 0 then
            j = j + 1
            result[j] = {}
        end
        result[j][#result[j]+1] = t[i]
    end
    return result
end

output = tablecut({'15', '62', '14', '91', '33', '55', '29', '4'}, 4)
for i = 1, #output do
    for j = 1, #output[i] do
        io.write(tostring(output[i][j])..'  ')
    end
    print()
end
```

output:

```
15  62  14  91  
33  55  29  4
```

And I am trying to find the minima from the cut lists so the output would look like this:

```
15  62  14  91  
min = 14
33  55  29  4
min = 4
```

---

Edit: If its of any importance this is how I got it to work on Lua 5.3 but there is no table.move function on Lua 5.1. I can't remember how my thought function worked when I wrote this code.

```
function indexOf(array, value)
  for i, v in ipairs(array) do
      if v == value then
          return i
      end
  end
  return nil
end


Indicies = {}
Answers = {}

function chunks(lst, size)
  local i = 1
  local count = 0
  return function()
    if i > #lst then return end
    local chunk = table.move(lst, i, i + size -1, 1, {})
    i = i + size
    count = count + 1
    return count, chunk
  end
end

local a = {91,52,19,59,38,29,58,11,717,91,456,49,30,62,43,8,17,15,26,22,13,10,2,23} --Test list
for i, chunk in chunks(a, 4) do
    x=math.min(a)
    print(string.format("#%d: %s", i, table.concat(chunk, ",")))
    table.sort(chunk)
    print(math.min(chunk[1]))
    table.insert(Answers, chunk[1])
    table.insert(Indicies, (indexOf(a, chunk[1])))
```

Output:

```
#1: 91,52,19,59
19
#2: 38,29,58,11
11
#3: 717,91,456,49
49
```

Comment: any ideas? this is not a coding service

Comment: @Piglet my bad for the bad explanation, a while back I wrote a code that did work, but I can't seem to remember how the code works. I set the code to the question, I am thinking maybe if I could remember how the code works, I could refactor the code to Lua 5.1 due to some functions not being available in 5.1 such as "table.move".

Comment: if `table.move` is not part of 5.1 anymore implement it yourself

Comment: Looking at your old code, I'd say you're better off just re-writing the whole thing from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your table cut function could be simplified, and your output for loop needs you use an iterator if you want to get an output simply like you do in your 5.3 script.

```lua
function cuttable(t,n)
  local binned = {}
  
  for i=1,#t,n do
      local bin = {}
        for j=1,n do
            table.insert(bin, t[i + ((j - 1) % n)])
        end
      table.insert(binned, bin)
  end
  
  return binned
end
```

For the for loop, we can use `ipairs` on the output of `cuttable` keeping things pretty simple, then we just do the same steps of concat then sort and print out our results.

```lua
for k, bin in ipairs(cuttable(a,4)) do
    local output = "#" .. k .. ":" .. table.concat(bin, ",")
    table.sort(bin)
    print(output)
    print(bin[1])
end
```

Output

```
#1:91,52,19,59
19
#2:38,29,58,11
11
#3:717,91,456,49
49
#4:30,62,43,8
8
#5:17,15,26,22
15
#6:13,10,2,23
2
```

Comment: Why are you sorting the "cut" tables though, a simple `math.min(unpack(t))` would've sufficed.

Comment: @LMD simply because it was the method the OP used in their 5.3 code. I do agree `unpack` might make more sense here, but perhaps they will also need the sorted sub tables in some future usecase the failed to include here.

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement the cutting would be using a for loop & `unpack`. I have handled the case of the length not being divisible by 4 after the for loop to (1) maximize performance (check doesn't need to be done every iteration) and (2) be able to directly pass the values to `math.min`, which doesn't accept `nil`s.

```lua
for i = 1, math.floor(#t / 4), 4 do
  print(unpack(t, i, i+4))
  print("min = " .. math.min(unpack(t, i, i+4)))
end
-- If #t is not divisible by 4, deal with the remaining elements
local remaining = #t % 4
if remaining > 0 then
  print(unpack(t, #t - remaining, remaining))
  print("min = " .. math.min(unpack(t, #t - remaining, remaining)))
end
```